# Is there a website which explain mysteries in wheel of time books?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

There were mysteries in the wheel of time books. For example, in The Great Hunt, a blood message were written on the wall of the prison in Fal Dara. Who wrote the message and free Fain? These mysteries were not directly explained in the following chapters, but an answer were implied in the later of the book.

I thought that Lanfear broke in the prison because the Trollish message mean "Daughter of the Night".

I am wondering if there is any website which explain mysteries in wheel of time books? I can check that after I've completed the book and see whether I am clear about the fact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the [FAQ](http://wotfaq.dragonmount.com/), (Personally, I find the older mirror [here](http://www.steelypips.org/wotfaq/) to be more user friendly):

By no means complete, but try the [encyclopedia](http://www.encyclopaedia-wot.org/) for book by book, chapter by chapter analysis (Section: The Books). It's complete up to Towers of Midnight.

There is also Leigh Butler’s [Wheel of Time Re-Read](http://www.tor.com/features/series/wot-reread) posts on the tor website which give helpful commentary for the series, and each post has a lot of comments so if anything is missed in the post itself, it's picked up there. But it does contain spoilers for later books, so isn't suitable to be read along with the books for a first time read through.

Answer (score 3):

The best place to go for this kind of thing is the Wheel of Time FAQ: http://wotfaq.dragonmount.com/

You can also check the numerous WoT wikis, but the FAQ (in my experience) is far more reliable, especially for information from the early books (up through *Path of Daggers*).